# Running Tapestry 5.3.8 on JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss7.x, tapestry

I have run into multiple problems during JBoss 5 to 7.1.1 migration. One of them is Tapestry not working at all.

The only "helpful" sign of this bug is that server responds with 404 whenewer I try to access my web app (WAR bundled within EAR) and displays "Not Found" in browser.

Even after turning every LOG4J output to DEBUG, no useful info was provided by server logs at all.

I tried upgrading different dependencies, changing war structure to comply with Tapestry specifications etc etc.

I have noticed that my application used `ClasspathURLConverter` accordingly to the one located here: https://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/HowToRunTapestry5OnJBoss5

However the converter is not working properly on JBoss 7

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was indeed in bad URL translation for Tapestry when it's looking for pages, components etc. (I had to dig really deep into the tapestry source code and debug it all the way down).

So I tried to look deeper in the VFS system and URL transformation. I have found 5+ links with the same code for converter to use (eg. http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-mpuwwlxm-eh.html). The problem with this implementation was if my JAR was located directly in `{myEar}/lib/` folder. I modified the code but resulted in the path pointing to exploded but empty jar in file system.

Then I have found another solution here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/172599
- much simpler and working.

So here is the final solution:

**AppModule.java:**

```
public static void contributeServiceOverride(MappedConfiguration<Class, Object> configuration) {
    configuration.add(ClasspathURLConverter.class, new MyClasspathURLConverterImpl());
}
```

**MyClasspathURLConverterImpl.java:**

```
public URL convert(URL url) {
    if (url != null && url.getProtocol().startsWith("vfs")) {
        try {
            return getRealFilePath(url.getPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getCause());
        }
    }
    return url;
}

private URL getRealFilePath(String urlString) throws IOException {
    VirtualFile vFile = VFS.getChild(urlString);
    URL physicalUrl = VFSUtils.getPhysicalURI(vFile).toURL();
    String physicalUrlStr = physicalUrl.toString();

    if (physicalUrlStr.contains(".jar")) {
        int jarIdx = physicalUrlStr.indexOf(".jar");
        String part1 = physicalUrlStr.substring(0, jarIdx + 4);
        String part2 = physicalUrlStr.substring(jarIdx + 4);

        String jarName = part1.substring(part1.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, jarIdx + 4);

        String dir = part1 + part2.substring(0, part2.indexOf("/"));

        String jarLocation = dir + "/" + jarName;
        String packageName = part2.substring(part2.indexOf("/"));
        if (packageName.startsWith("/contents")) {
            packageName = packageName.substring(9);
        }
        String result = "jar:" + jarLocation + "!" + packageName;
        physicalUrl = new URL(result);
    }
    return physicalUrl;
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-vfs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.14.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```